# Qt5: работа с QtSql, обращение к пустой базе данных

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4

Я обращаюсь к базе данных mysql:

```
void queryDealID()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    if (!query.exec("SELECT DealID FROM st_park_bukkit ORDER BY DealID DESC LIMIT 1;"))
    {
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query";
        return;
    }
    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    query.next();
    //   qDebug() << "Current DID from query " << query.value(rec.indexOf("DealID")).toString();

    if(query.value(rec.indexOf("DealID")).isNull())
    {
        CurrentDealID = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentDealID = query.value(rec.indexOf("DealID")).toInt();
    }
}
```

Когда она пустая, то у меня в дебаге вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
 QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

Как это поправить? Код работает, но я боюсь, что творятся страшные невидимые вещи.
Какова механика ошибки?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#isValid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для пустой таблицы надо просто проверять на валидность результат запроса

> bool QSqlQuery::isValid() const Returns true if the query is currently
>   positioned on a valid record; otherwise returns false.
>
> isValid() ... Возвращает true если запрос находится на валидной
>   записи, иначе возвращается false [см.тут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#isValid)

```
QSqlQuery query = ...

if( query.isValid() ) 
{
    // Здесь ваш код на случай если записи в таблице имеются, 
    // то есть запрос валиден

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    //...
}
```